# React - How can I import all my components into one

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I want to be able to access my e.g. HeaderRow in the App.js without having to import TableHeader in the App.js.

*My code is the following:*
**src/App.js**

```
import Table from './Components/Table';
```

**src/Components/Table.js**

```
import TableHeader from './TableHeader';
import TableBody from './TableBody';
import TableFooter from './TableFooter';
```

And in my TableHeader.js I have HeaderRow(component) and HeaderCell(component), in TableBody.js I have BodyRow(component) and BodyCell(component) ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your main Components create all the class that you wanna export
for example

```
class Table extends React.Component {
....
}
class TableHeader extends React.Component {
....
}
```

and then export them like this

```
export { Table, TableHeader };
```

to import them from another component simply

```
import {Table, TableHeader} from "./Component";
```

Comment: My main component is App and I want to be able to import only Table, and with that have access to all table inside components

Comment: well then put it in your main component and import it

Answer (score 0):

Without an import statement your App.js code will never be able to find the HeaderRow. You could create a index.js file and export all the components there so you can create a single import statement

Comment: I want my table to be that one import statment that your talking

Comment: See Abdeslem Charif's answer